# quarto presentation multi-column toc

Tags: r, r-markdown, reveal.js, xaringan, quarto

Wondering how to get multi-column `toc` in [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) presentation. The code of `Test1.qmd` is given below:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "A B c"
format:
  revealjs: 
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc-depth: 2
    toc-location: body
    toc-title: "Contents"
    css: styles.css
---

# Intro1

## Intro11

AS


# Intro2

## Intro21

AS
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of existing YAML multi-column `TOC`.
To achieve the desired result you could place CSS code below, inside your `styles.css`:

```
.reveal ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;  /* space-around */
}
```

Just for the record, one can put content in [side by side columns](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#multiple-columns).
Run again `.qmd`:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "M Yaseen"
format:
  revealjs: 
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc-depth: 2
    toc-location: body
    toc-title: "Contents"
    css: styles.css
---

# Intro 1

## Intro 1.1

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="40%"}
Content in left column
:::

::: {.column width="60%"}
Content in right column
:::

::::


# Intro 2

## Intro 2.1

Content...


# Intro 3

## Intro 3.1

Content...  


# Intro 4

## Intro 4.1

Content...
```

Output:
[image]